# Calculate sum in a short way

Tags: summation

The question is like this:
Let the sum $$\sum_{n=1}^9 \frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}$$ written in its lowest terms be $\frac{p}{q}$. Find $p-q$
I tried to calculate it by putting in values  1 to 9 and actually calculating the value of the sum, but it was too long and I don't want to use a calculator. I messed with the expression for quite a while only to realize it was in vain. Please help. thanks in advance.

Comment: $\phantom{}$TLSCPC

Comment: @ Jack D'Aurizio: aramaic-english?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\frac1{n(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac12\left[\frac1{n(n+1)}-\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)}\right]
$$

Comment: Is the answer 83?

Comment: Yes,  that is correct up to a factor of $-1$.

Comment: Oh yeah right it was numerator minus denominator. -83. My bad.

Comment: I like this. I usually decompose it into 3 fractions. Never thought of doing this.